# How to add custom UIButton in table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom `UIButton` that I need to add to my dynamic table view cell. None of the tutorials I've used has worked for me. My `UIButton` only appears when the cell is clicked, then quickly vanishes. When I click the button the app crashes and I get `...ViewController addButtonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. What do I need to do here?

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var addFriendButton: UIButton!

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
            println("Hey")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            var friendsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddFriendsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

            friendsCell.addFriendButton.tag = indexPath.row

            friendsCell.addFriendButton.addTarget(self, action: "addButtonPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            return friendsCell

        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this: (add '**:**' in your selector name)

```
friendsCell.addFriendButton.addTarget(self, action: "addButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

I hope this will solve your problem of un recognised selector.

Comment: Yes, that worked! But my button (I'm using a custom image) is still only appearing when the cell is clicked. Why is that happening?

Comment: I think you have styled your cell while setting the selected state in Interface builder

Comment: I'm sorry, what does that mean? And what should I check?

Comment: No I'm adding it via storyboard

Comment: try to comment this line : friendsCell.addFriendButton.tag = indexPath.row   and then test .....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80444/discussion-between-m-abdul-sami-and-dperk).

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confuse, the function below should not be an outlet:

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
            println("Hey")
}
```

You should have a button in the TableViewCell and just a method in the ViewController, are they supposed to be the same button?

If so remove the bottom from the ViewController and its outlet and leave just the function to be called.

Comment: Did that fixed your problem?

Comment: Fortunately the answer below helped. That mistake actually didn't matter.